# How to add multiple models at runtime in tf_serving without unloading the previous models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to add a new model in `tensorflow_model_server` using the following code:

```
from tensorflow_serving.apis import model_service_pb2_grpc
from tensorflow_serving.apis import model_management_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.config import model_server_config_pb2

import grpc

def add_model_config(host, name, base_path, model_platform):
  channel = grpc.insecure_channel(host)
  stub = model_service_pb2_grpc.ModelServiceStub(channel)
  request = model_management_pb2.ReloadConfigRequest()
  model_server_config = model_server_config_pb2.ModelServerConfig()

  #Create a config to add to the list of served models
  config_list = model_server_config_pb2.ModelConfigList()
  one_config = config_list.config.add()
  one_config.name= name
  one_config.base_path=base_path
  one_config.model_platform=model_platform

  model_server_config.model_config_list.CopyFrom(config_list)

  request.config.CopyFrom(model_server_config)

  print(request.IsInitialized())
  print(request.ListFields())

  response = stub.HandleReloadConfigRequest(request,10)
  if response.status.error_code == 0:
      print("Reload sucessfully")
      return True
  else:
      print("Reload failed!")
      print(response.status.error_code)
      print(response.status.error_message)
      return False
```

But whenever I try to execute it the server unloads all of the previous models. Is it possible to keep serving all the models and then add a new model ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to just add a new model while keeping the previous ones already loaded.

What I have been doing is to always keep the last model config list on disk, and when I need to refresh the models for any reason (either add or remove or update), I read that config file from disk, and do the proper modification, and call the HandleReloadConfigRequest() with the full config list, and then save it to disk again.

The file on disk (say `/models/models.config`) becomes the authoritative record of what models have been loaded into tf.serve at any given time. This way you can recover from a tf.serve reboot and have the comfort knowing that it will load the correct models. The option for specifying the config file during server start is `--model_config_file /models/models.config`.